# 'Clay Pigeon Shooting' Achievement not progressing

Tags: steam, achievements, payday-2

I still haven't found a solution for this odd situation yet, but for some reason killing snipers with flechette rounds (on any shotgun I use) doesn't lower the counter of how many I need to kill for the 'Clay Pigeon Shooting' achievemtn.

For example, I was in a Nightclub mission where I shot 3 snipers, checked my inventory, and the progress was still at 0/10.

Answer (score 5):

The mission is bugged and will not properly display how many snipers you've killed.  I've done this mission before and you just have to keep a mental check of how many snipers you've killed. Once you've killed 10, you'll get the achievement and the relevant weapon mods.

Comment: ohh i was thinking that was they case but didn't want to waste the time doing it in case it wasn't - thanks :D

Comment: @caek No problem :) It's sad that it's not like TF2, where it will actively check your progress in an achievement, and that you have to just keep killing whatever enemy the achievement is for until you see the achievement pop up.